# Page loading stops and cannot be resumed when changing tabs in Android Tor Browser

Tags: browser, firefox-for-android, tor, browser-tabs, orbot

I'm trying out the Tor browser on Android 9.0 (device is not rooted). When I open a page and change tabs before the new page is fully loaded, the loading process is interrupted and cannot be resumed. Changing back to the "inactivated" tab and reloading does not work, the tab has to be closed and the page needs to be loaded from a new tab.

As usual, the Tor browser comes bundled with NoScript and HTTPS Everywhere, I'm also using the uBlock Origin extension (any opinion on this?). Background data is disabled for all apps except messengers and the max. number of background processes (developer options) is set to zero. I have tried changing the security settings as well as disabling uBO, but the problem persists... Now that I think of it, I encountered the same issue using the Brave browser on Android.

Can anyone reproduce this behaviour and tell me what's causing it? This is extremely annoying, as using Tor increases loading time with some pages, I therefore want to be able to switch to a different tab while waiting.

Comment: I have been using it occasionally on Android 10 but never faced this. Wonder if this due to internet connection?

Comment: Good question, haven't tried this on WLAN yet. But I suspect some underlying Android issue, as I encountered this behaviour with two different browsers on two completely different devices (Brave vs. Tor, Android 4.2 vs. 9.0) as well as two different mobile carriers/contracts

Comment: I have and had Brave too on 9 but never faced this

Comment: Do browser tabs in Android require background data in order to stay active?

Comment: Depends on what's on the tab - ads, scripts need more data. I would say, yes they do. Chrome restricts content refresh of background data and save power

Comment: Background basically means that the app is not being displayed on the screen, right? What about max. number of background processes in the developer options, does this have any effect?

Comment: I meant background as in app is active on screen but has multiple tabs and inactive tabs =background. If app is not active I don't think they need background data, as nothing is being refreshed. IDK about process option in developer